# Styling with Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 in Datatables, how do I allow both original background image and new image in the header?

Tags: css, datatables, zurb-foundation, datatables-1.10, zurb-foundation-5

I am trying to have images show in an extended width Datatables header. The styling is using Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 framework.

Please see site http://iprobesolutions.com/test2 which is using Zurb Foundation 5.5.3 [image: CSS]

The background images show up fine in this [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/setbon/0s405fyf/) so I don't know how to replicate the issue in a fiddle.

This is an example of the CSS for the background image:

```
table.table1 thead .beyer, 
#example table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc .beyer  {
background-image: url("https://placehold.it/264x140.jpg") no-repeat center        `center;
 height:264px;
 width:140px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center top;
 height: 10rem;
 background-size: contain;
}
```

According to Mozilla:

> With CSS3, you can apply multiple backgrounds to elements. These are layered atop one another with the first background you provide on top and the last background listed in the back. Only the last background can include a background color.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds

I don't know if this is the way to solve this problem. But even if it is, since the file https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.foundation.css is not hosted by me but pulled down from their CDN, how am I supposed to disable their original background image and consequently combine the two background images in one line of code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to my old front end teacher the following was clarified:

table.dataTable thead .sorting appears to have roughly the same specificity as table.table1 thead .beyer. dataTables.foundation.css has been moved to now load before the datatables.css, table.table1 thead .beyer.

Answer (score 1):

Your styles need to come after the datatables css files.

```
 <!--data tables -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.foundation.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.foundation.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.foundation.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/css/fixedHeader.foundation.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.foundation.css"/>


 <!-- other styles -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.css">
 <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundicons/3.0.0/foundation-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation-footer.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/datatables.css">
```

Try putting your styles in /css/data/tables.css

Also it looks like you're importing foundation twice.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.min.css"/>
```

Comment: thanks. I did what you suggested. The problem persists. Any suggestions as to next step ?

Comment: You're example link still has the original order of css files. Another way to do it is to use !important in your css, however its not best practice to do so. Change datatables.css line 55 to `background-image: url(https://placehold.it/264x140.jpg) !important;`

Comment: The order was changed not sure why it's not showing up on your end. See screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/55zg4ee65tmioru/Screenshot%202017-02-25%2004.13.36.png?dl=0 When you say to change datatables.css line 55, since I'm using the file from their CDN, how can I change it unless I would download and selfhost it ?